# PHP dynamic get Mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have a PHP document where I get mysql info:

```
$db = mysql_select_db('opinaol', $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database.");  
$search=$_POST['search']; 

$data = 'SELECT * FROM `contratosnmx` WHERE `_rowid_` = 2 '; 
$query = mysql_query($data) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error()); 
$data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

So the form shows the info.

What I want is a way to change the `_rowid_` on the page so I can select the row number and have the form change the info displayed.

Comment: Read about html forms.

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `_rowid_` using GET parameters.

```
$rowid = 1; // default value
if (isset($_GET['_rowid_'])) {
    $rowid = intval($_GET['_rowid_']);
}
$data = 'SELECT * FROM `contratosnmx` WHERE `_rowid_` = '.$rowid; // no need to escape $rowid value because we used intval().
```

If your page has url `http://domain.com/page.php`, then you can request information with *rowid* = 10 using next url:
`http://domain.com/page.php?_rowid_=10`

Comment: But is there any way to chose the id right in the document? not with the url?

Comment: You can create another form with field _rowid_. For example, <form action="page.php" method="get"><input type="text" name="_rowid_" value="2" /></form>. You can load different ids by submitting this form.